# Consulta sobre list.sort

Tags: python, lista, ordenamiento

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo y funciona:

```
def myFunc(e):
  return (e[1])

cars = [['Ford',2012,5], ['Subaru',2010,4], ['BMW',2010,3], ['VW',2011,2]]
cars.sort(key=myFunc)

print(cars)
```

Mi consulta es:

Es posible pasarle parámetros a la funcion **myFunc**, de tal manera que, dependiendo del parámetro el orden sea distinto...???

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Vaya pregunta!, ahora elaboro mi respuesta

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. Recomiendo que hagas el recorrido para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También estaría bien que revisaras Cómo preguntar para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. –

Comment: @AntoniSamillanDeLaCruz la pregunta no es del tipo *"Tengo que hacer esto"*, pues el OP muestra lo que ha echo y le funciona, solo tiene una duda que requiere una amplia explicación, la cual estoy elaborando :)

Answer (score 5):

Pues no... lastimosamente no pero sería interesante, el parámetro `key` de `list.sort()` y `sorted()` toma una función que solo debe tener un argumento y debe devolver una key que es usada para ordenar, ahora bien lo que buscas no es una locura, pero no es por esa forma, podrías usar una función `lambda` o un truquito del modulo `operator`:

**Usando `lambda`:**

```
cars = [['Ford',2012,5], ['Subaru',2010,4], ['BMW',2010,3], ['VW',2011,2]]
#ordenar por año
cars.sort(key=lambda car: car[1])
#>> [['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['BMW', 2010, 3], ['VW', 2011, 2], ['Ford', 2012, 5]]
print(cars)
#ordenar por nombre
cars.sort(key=lambda car: car[0])
print(cars)
#>>[['BMW', 2010, 3], ['Ford', 2012, 5], ['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['VW', 2011, 2]]
```

**Ordenar usando el modulo `operator`:**

El modulo `operator` viene por defecto con python y este tiene un par de funciones que se crearon especialmente para este problema: `itemgetter`, `attrgetter` (solo mostraré el uso de `itemgetter` porque funciona en este tipo de listas, `attrgetter` trabaja en listas de objetos):

```
from operator import itemgetter

cars = [['Ford',2012,5], ['Subaru',2010,4], ['BMW',2010,3], ['VW',2011,2]]
#ordenar por año
cars.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
print(cars)
#>> [['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['BMW', 2010, 3], ['VW', 2011, 2], ['Ford', 2012, 5]]
#ordenar por nombre
cars.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
print(cars)
#>>[['BMW', 2010, 3], ['Ford', 2012, 5], ['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['VW', 2011, 2]]
```

[Aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) tienes la documentación sobre el ordenamiento de listas en python.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de las respuestas que te han dado, lo más sencillo sería que la función de ordenación te la dé una función hecha a medida con los criterios de ordenación que necesites.

Por ejemplo:

```py
def myFunc(arg):
    def sorter(item):
        if arg == "Fabricante":
            return item[0]
        elif arg == "Año":
            return item[1]
        elif arg == "Año DESC":
            return -item[1]
        else:
            return item[2]
    return sorter

sorted_cars = sorted(cars, key=myFunc("Año DESC"))
```

En `myFunc` se construye la función `sorter` que dará la pauta para ordenar los elementos de la lista. En el ejemplo se ve cómo se puede invertir el orden simplemente cambiando el signo del valor, si tener que usar la opción `reverse` de `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

## función `sorted()` y `sort()`

La función `sorted()` solo implementa un simple método de ordenamiento ascendente (por defecto), esta función se puede emplear en cualquier iterable (listas, tuplas, diccionarios, objetos generadores, etc.), en cambio la función `sort()` solo funciona con listas, de ahí su representación `list.sort()`.

## Parámetro `key`

Tanto `sorted()` como `sort()` tienen un parámetro llamado `key` para especificar una función, la cual se ejecutara (o llamara) en cada iteración del elemento iterable.

Vamos a tomar como ejemplo tu código. En este hay una lista llamada `cars` que asu vez contiene otras listas, que vendría a ser la información de los carros, al ser una lista se puede utilizar su método `sort()`, a este método le estas pasando un argumento llamado `key`, propio del método, en el cual le indicas que ejecute la función `myFunc` en cada iteración de la lista.
La función `myFunc` recibe un parámetro `e`, pero... ¿Por qué no da error si al utilizar la función en el método `sort()` no se le pasa ninguno?. Pues la respuesta sencilla es que si recibe el parámetro, ¿y cual es?, el parámetro es la *"sub lista"* que contiene la lista `cars`, de ahí viene que la función se encargue de obtener y retornar el segundo elemento de la lista. Podemos probarlo de esta manera

```py
def myFunc(e):
  return (e[1])

lista = ['hola','mundo','funcion','sort']

print(myFunc(lista))
#salida -> 'mundo'
```

Esto pasara con cada elemento del iterable que le pasemos.

Bien muchas veces las operaciones que queremos hacer son muy sencillas y no es muy común hacerlas en funciones como tu lo haces, mayormente se utilizan las *lambda expressions*

## Expresiones `lambda`

Las expresiones lambda son una forma fácil, sencilla y simplificada de escribir una función, estas son funciones anónimas cuya sitaxis es:

```
lambda parametros: expresion
```

Las funciones `lambda` se utilizan para hacer acciones concretas, mayormente se utiliza estas métodos como `sort()`, `sorted()`, entre otros. Tu función de ordenamiento puede ser convertida a una función `lambda` de esta forma.
`lambda e: e[1]`, esto quiere decir que recibirá un parámetro `e`(que en este caso será una lista) y retornara `e[1]`. Quedando el código así:

```
cars = [['Ford',2012,5], ['Subaru',2010,4], ['BMW',2010,3], ['VW',2011,2]]
cars.sort(key=lambda e: e[1]) #ordenara por año

print(cars)
```

En cuanto a tu pregunta

> Es posible pasarle parámetros a la funcion `myFunc`, de tal manera que, dependiendo del parámetro el orden sea distinto...???

La respuesta es No, si lo que quieres es ordenarlos a través de uno de sus indices, como mostré anteriormente, tendras que hacerlo en la expresión lambda. Una cosa de las *expresiones lambda* es que podemos tener creada una y almacenarla en una variable

```py
expresion = lambda e:e[0]
```

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una funcion y aplicar la lambda dentro de esa funcion

```
def ordenar(e,i=1,order=True):
    return sorted(e,key=lambda e: e[i], reverse=order)

ordenado = ordenar(cars)
print(ordenado)
#salida -> [['Ford', 2012, 5], ['VW', 2011, 2], ['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['BMW', 2010, 3]]

ordenado = ordenar(cars,order=False)
print(ordenado)
#salida -> [['Subaru', 2010, 4], ['BMW', 2010, 3], ['VW', 2011, 2], ['Ford', 2012, 5]]
```

para algunos ordenamientos mas complejos se uso el modulo `itemgetter` para el ordenamiento complejo. Si quieres que ponga un ejemplo de como utilizarlo avísame, pues la pregunta no es *"como ordenar una lista manteniendo un orden"*. Puedes leer mas en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/howto/sorting.html#:%7E:text=Las%20listas%20de%20Python%20tienen,para%20ordenar%20datos%20usando%20Python.)